# Issue while Sending Message and making call together

Tags: android

In my application, I need to call a number along with sending a message to that number. But when I send the message and initiate the call, the call is getting dropped instantly. If I'm not sending message before calling, the calling works fine. Please help me with a solution. Thanks.

For calling I'm Using :

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
context.startActivity(callIntent);
```

For Messaging :

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I initiated the message sending after 3 seconds from making call, both are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to call a number and send a message at the same time, you can try something like this:

Use a `public static boolean variable say: sIsSendMessage = false;`

and then

```
sIsSendMessage  = true;
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
context.startActivity(callIntent);
```

and then in

```
public void onResume() {
       if(sIsSendMessage) {
              sIsSendMessage = false;
              SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
              smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null, null);
       }
}
```

Since after ending your call, again your activity will come on front and its `onResume()` will be called, you can send message in this method.

Comment: For sending message I'm using SMS Manager class of Android, so I'm not navigating to any activity there. After calling the send message function, when I try to initiate the call, the calling screen comes and suddenly displays "call ended".

Comment: Yes...the number is correct. The issue happens when I'm sending sms before the call otherwise the call will work fine.

Comment: Have you tried above method which I have given. Try it, I believe it will definitely solve your problem.

Comment: What network are you using for your test? Is it a GSM network or a CDMA network?